# How to use if-statement with forfiles to match a pattern and delete if older than x day?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, if-statement

How to use if else statement in forfiles to match a filename pattern and keep files for 90 days deleting older files, and if pattern not matched then keep for 30 days.

The script need to check a path recursively for all files and retain file for 90 days if *pattern.log is matched and for all others retain for only 30 days. 
- The folders should be kept anyways;
- This contains a huge number of file and using only Powershell makes it very slow and take more than a days time, so finally I'm stuck with using forfiles with if-else condition. 
I'm fairly new to scripting and unable to find how I can use if-else matching a pattern.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Data | ForEach-Object {
    $serverpath = $_.FullName
    forfiles /p "$serverpath\Logs" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del /Q /F @file"
}
```

This code works fine and delete all the files older than 30 days. However, Now I am required to keep a matching pattern file name for 90 days which I'm stuck with. Please help.

Comment: There is no need for `forfiles` or `cmd /c`. Pipe to `Where-Object` to filter for what you want to remove, then pipe to `Remove-Item` to remove the items. See the PowerShell help topics for the cmdlets for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **LotPings** and **T-Me**, with your suggestions I combined and was able to fix my situation with the following lines of code that I'm pasting here for anybody's reference:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Data" -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
if($_.LastWriteTime -le (get-date).AddDays(-90) -or ($_.Name -notlike "*pattern.log" -and $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))) {
    Remove-Item $_.FullName
    }
}
```

Also, the reason why the other scripts were taking a long time was, I was storing files information in the variables and I noticed that as the number files is huge in this scenario it was consuming a lot of RAM 10+GB of RAM and I had to force close it. The Scheduled task that I had a schedule of running everyday using the script was actually taking about 5 days to finish and hence was failing for about 4-5 days on each run. But now it only takes about a couple of hours and the issue I had initially is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the old batch executable `forfiles` powershell is fully capable of doing it:

```
$Path = "C:\Data"
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File  
ForEach($File in $Files)  { 
    if ($File.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)){
        Remove-Item $File
    } elseif ($File.Name -notlike "*.log" -and $File.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)){
        Remove-Item $File
    }
}
```

Replace `$File.Name -notlike "*.log"` with your patern.

Comment: Forfiles is a compiled executable. It is not a cmdlet.

Comment: @T-Me: Thank you for your suggestion, however, this is not helping the situation, as the folder contains millions of files if not billions, mostly flat txt and zip files. I'm not sure why but when this scans .zip file of size a couple of GB's this take times.

Answer (score 1):

As `Remove-Item` accepts piped input, a single `Where-Object` with the comparisons is IMO more elegant.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Data\Logs -Files -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-90) -or
  ( $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-30) -and
    $_.Extension -ne '.Log' ) } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`

I'm curious under what conditions (file number/size) `forfiles` is superior in speed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion this one looks nice and well formatted. However, again this is taking a long time while iterating through a zip file of size a few GB's. Not sure if zip files are causing the problem.
When I run forfiles it works fine, removing the files recursively. The directory contains about ~12TB of data contains mostly flat data files like, csv, log files and zip files. 
I'm not sure if zip file is causing all this trouble. :(

Comment: Neither forfiles nor Get-ChildItem will open zip files. Your above forfile command appends `\Logs` to the path; is this the reason to be faster as only iterating this subtree? Changed the answer to use `C:\Data\Logs`